# ubuntu server monitoring and troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, monitoring, rackspace

I have a rackspace cloud server running Ubuntu 10. The http font-end is nginx 1.0.2. There are multiple java web app instances running on Play!Framework, which in turn built on Netty stack.

I found the http connection to nginx broken from time to time, and I suspect one of the java web app instance caused the trouble. However it breaks the http connection to nginx which is weird. I am pretty nervous about this issue. Anyone has any suggestion on how to monitor and troubleshoot the system?

For the moment I think some tools with http interface to display history data of CPU/Memory/Files opened etc for each process could help me a lot.

What do you recommend?

Thanks in advance,
Green

Answer (score 0):

I think here is Munin the right way

http://munin-monitoring.org/

Because it is easy to install have many features like email Notification
and many Plugins.

Other think is nagios ^^ but nagios is a little bit difficult and better for a server infrastructure

Greez bull

[image: Munin]